# Run Airflow CLI commands for private Cloud Composer environment via SSH tunnel

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I want to access a private Google Cloud Composer 2 environment directly from my local machine and execute Airflow CLI commands. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-airflow-cli#private-ip) mentions multiple ways to connect to a private environment, but nothing for my particular use case. I either have to log in to a GCE instance in the same VPC or allow public endpoint access.

What I am currently trying to do is to create an SSH tunnel or Socks5 Proxy to a VM instance (bastion-host) in the same VPC as my Composer environment. Then export the PROXY variables in my shell and run the CLI command with `gcloud`

```bash
gcloud compute ssh bastion-host -- -ND 8888

export {HTTP,HTTPS}_PROXY=socks5://localhost:8888

gcloud composer environments run composer --location europe-west1 dags list
```

But I am receiving the following error

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ProxyError): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='composer.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/projects/my-project/locations/europe-west1/environments/composer?alt=json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `gcloud composer environments run` is not only accessing the GKE cluster via `kubectl`, but also making some Google API calls. As a workaround I also had to set the `NO_PROXY` variable

```bash
export NO_PROXY=googleapis.com
```